# How can i use a numericUpDown to move to specific location text in richTextBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the listView selected index i select item and display the file content in richTextBox:

```
void lvnf_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.SelectedIndices[0]].Text);

                int resultsnumber = 0;
                int start = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
                int startIndex = 0;
                int index = 0;
                string word = textBox1.Text;
                Color selectionColor = richTextBox1.SelectionColor;
                word = textBox1.Text.Replace("\r\n", "\n");

                while ((index = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(word, startIndex)) != -1)
                {
                    richTextBox1.Select(index, word.Length);
                    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Yellow;
                    startIndex = index + word.Length;
                    resultsnumber ++;
                }

                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = start;
                richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = selectionColor;

                label16.Text = resultsnumber.ToString();
                label16.Visible = true;
                numericUpDown1.Maximum = resultsnumber;
                numericUpDown1.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
```

And i have the numericUpDown changedvalue event

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

for example if i have in the numericUpDown the maximum value of 4 that's 4 results in the richTextBox text.

Each result is in another place in the text.
What i want to do is when i move up down with the numericUpDown it will jump in the richTextBox to the result location in the text.

I think it should be that if the first result started in index 0 and ended in index 20 then jump to this result show this result.

If the third result is started in index 76 and ended in index 83 so if i selected in the numericUpDown the value 3 jump to this result location.

Ok this is what i did now it was quite easy but i have a problem reseting the variable:

It was easy to do it but i have a problem reseting the variables when selecting another item each time in the listView. I want to reset the List and also to set the numericUpDown1 to value 0 when selecting other item. But then it's going to the numericUpDown1_ValueChanged item before it's adding items to the List and throw exception since the List Count and the numericUpDown1 value are 0.

In top of form1 created a new List

```
private List<int> results = new List<int>();
```

In the listView selectedindex event:

```
void lvnf_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items[ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.SelectedIndices[0]].Text);

                results = new List<int>();
                numericUpDown1.Value = 0;
                int resultsnumber = 0;
                int start = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
                int startIndex = 0;
                int index = 0;
                string word = textBox1.Text;
                Color selectionColor = richTextBox1.SelectionColor;
                word = textBox1.Text.Replace("\r\n", "\n");

                while ((index = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(word, startIndex)) != -1)
                {
                    richTextBox1.Select(index, word.Length);
                    richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Yellow;
                    startIndex = index + word.Length;
                    resultsnumber ++;
                    results.Add(startIndex);
                }

                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = start;
                richTextBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = selectionColor;

                label16.Text = resultsnumber.ToString();
                label16.Visible = true;
                numericUpDown1.Maximum = results.Count -1;
                numericUpDown1.Enabled = true;

                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = results[(int)numericUpDown1.Value];
                richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
            }
        }
```

In the numericupdown1 valuechanged event

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (results.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Results Count Value is 0 Check It !!!!!");
            }
            else
            {
                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = results[(int)numericUpDown1.Value];
                richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
            }
        }
```

When selecting first item in the listView it's fine.
But then when selecting any other item i want that the results List and the numericUpDown will be reset to empty and 0.

The problem is when i set the numericUpDown1 Value to 0 it's jumping to the valuechanged event before it's adding the results to the List so it's giving the exception.

Comment: Well, don't lose the *start* variable values.  Store them in a `List<int>` and it gets trivial to implement this.

Comment: It's working fine.  Never mind my edit. Sorry.